How to delete AWSALB Cookies?
We have our authFlow as ALB->AWS-Cognito->ourApp, when we login the AWSALB is setting the cookie after successful authentication, when we are logging out these cookies are still active and we are able to replay the session,
We tried to expire the cookie from our frontend using :
HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0=deleted;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;HttpOnly");
        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1=deleted;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;HttpOnly");

but it didnt help, what would be the right way of expiring these cookies ?
